# В чем разница между роптать, сетовать а жаловаться

Tags: словоупотребление, выбор-слова, разница

Прочитав объяснение и примеры приведенные в Викисловаре.

Мне кажется

- жалуется тот, кто просто говорит о том, что ему плохо, у него болит; *жаловаться* - это нейтральное слово
- *сетовать* - мне кажется, что это слово ничем не отличается от слова *жаловаться*, кроме того, что это слово книжное
- *роптать*, по моему является очень негативным словом. Ропщущий человек жалуется из-за пустяков, делает это слишком часто. Роптать - это переливать свое неудовольствие на других, окружающих человек.

Правда ли это, что мне кажется про разницы между этими словами?

Для информации, привожу цитированные фрагменты статьи из Викисловаря.

> **роптать**:
>
> высказывать недовольство кем-либо, чем-либо, обиду на кого-либо, что-либо
>
> ◆ Он был в горе, в досаде, роптал на весь свет, сердился на несправедливость судьбы, негодовал на несправедливость людей и, однако же, не мог отказаться от новых попыток. Н. В. Гоголь, «Мертвые души», 1842 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса русского языка, см. Список литературы)
>
> ◆ За спиной у хозяина роптали, называли его последними именами, но дальше ропота и разговоров дело не шло. А. И. Пантелеев, «Ленька Пантелеев», 1938-1952 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса русского языка, см. Список литературы)
>
> **сетовать**:
>
> книжн. то же, что жаловаться
>
> ◆ Хозяйка стала угощать его пивом и сетовала на нынешнее дождливое время. Ф. М. Решетников, «Тетушка Опарина», 1868 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса русского языка, см. Список литературы)
>
> **жаловаться**:
>
> высказывать жалость
>
> ◆ Вон собаки. Они жрут только мясо и рыбу, и никто из них не жалуется на зубную боль. Рытхэу, «Пусть уходит лёд», 1966 г.

Comment: ***роптать*** не то, чтобы сильно негативное, просто есть в нём сопутствующее значение осуждения или обвинения сторонних факторов в своих проблемах

Comment: Или слово "сетовать" уже в значительной мере вышло из употребления, или оно изначально отличалось от "жаловаться". Просто не могу себе представить гневного: "Я буду сетовать!"

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка не только осуждения, а очень эмоционального. Как закипание воды - вроде она ещё стоит более-менее спокойно, но пузырики уже идут так часто, что того и гляди закипит. Это переходный момент, неустойчивое положение, бифуркация, ещё вода не закипела, но уже и не спокойная.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `роптать` is a quite strong (but also bookish) one. It's *almost* "uprise", "riot", but not quite. I'd say a murmur. "А люди все роптали и роптали, наверное, справедливости хотят";
- `сетовать` is bookish for "complain", but don't really expect a change when doing so;
- "to complain" is exactly the meaning of `жаловаться`, but more broadly accepted in the language. "Выйдешь без шапки — потом не жалуйся, что простудился!". Further point is that `жаловаться` also means complaining to an authority, while `сетовать` is more brooding without expected consequences.

For me `роптать` is, while *very* bookish, also about multiple people. "The murmurs started again at his infidelity, but each of them was quite, when he locked at them directly." While both other verbs are about single-person complaining.

Comment: It's pretty rude to answer in English) The poster wrote in Russian.

Comment: That's not a problem. Please answer in the language you feel most comfortable in :)

Comment: Русская группа Ария поет в одной из своих песни (про Понтия Пилата): _Ты должен не роптать, а терпеть_, но это может быть просто поэтический прием, их песни сочиняются поэтами.

Comment: @VCH250 most readers here are foreigners, so he has a point. There happened to be http://RUS.stackexchange.com forum for in-depth discussion by native speakers :-D

Comment: Good answer. I'd add that "жаловаться" can also be used for writing complains (e.g. "опять горячей воды нет! я буду жаловаться!"), or for talking to authorities (e.g. "я на тебя маме пожалуюсь!"), while "сетовать" is only for talking about something you didn't like to someone who doesn't have any power over the situation.

Comment: @Alissa: thank you, you are right. I updated the answer.

Comment: `about multiple people` - "он начал роптать" - нет, ропот как существительное в самом деле подразумевает некую толпу, в которой не вычленить индивидуальные выкрики. Как "гуд", "шум" - это описание ситуации. Но к глаголу это напрямую не относится. "Я начал роптать" - вполне себе единственное число. Да, подразумевается, что мне, надеюсь, удастся и остальных подбить и начнется коллективный ропот, но вовсе не обязательно.

Answer (score 3):

**Роптать** можно на вышестоящих, перешёптываться в поисках одобрения других и даже возможного бунта. Поэтому нельзя сказать *я ропщу*, ропот - это всегда коллективное и понятное лишь при взгляде со стороны.

**Сетуют**  не ожидая серьёзной реакции, как правило малознакомым людям и/или о вещах которые невозможно изменить (погода, невезение и т. п.)

**Жаловаться** - это вызывать жалость, сочувствие, эмпатию. Жалуются когда ожидают от слушателя каких-либо действий

Если рабочий рассказывает директору предприятия, что денег не хватает, он жалуется. А если директор об этом говорит рабочему, то он сетует.

Comment: `Поэтому нельзя сказать я ропщу` - а "мы роптим" можно сказать? :-D как раз коллективный ропот состоит из множества индивидуальных. Я ропщу и надеюсь, что по моему примеру мои соседи тоже начнут роптать. Может у меня получится их к этому подтолкнуть, а может нет - тут как повезёт. Но я уже ропщу, а мой сосед пока ещё не ропщет.

Comment: @Arioch мы роптим тоже не говорят, как раз по той же причине, нельзя понять, что это ропот, если сам в нём участвуешь. Поэтому форму "ропщу" и "ропщем" в Нацкорпусе можно увидеть почти исключительно с частицей "не".

Comment: ну "почти" - это всё же не "нельзя", я вот пример сходу привёл, весьма узкого смысла, но в своём контексте вполне нормального

Comment: @Arioch и выглядит ваш пример крайне неестественно. Все эти "почти" касаются иронического употребления (где-то 2-3 на сотню случаев) или обращения клирика ко своей пастве, где, хоть и употреблено "мы", из контекста понятно, что сам-то он не ропщет.

Comment: Я не согласен, что он неестественный, хотя это дело вкуса.

Answer (score 1):

В наше время (!) "жаловаться" и "сетовать" это практические одно и то же; второе слово более старое, книжное.
"Роптать" примерно соответствует "словесно возмущаться (против чего-то, по какому-то поводу)".